# How can I combine set-strictMode -version 2 in a PowerShell Script (not function) with the param statement?

Tags: powershell

When I run the following script, I get a *The variable '$windowHeight' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.* error message.

```
set-strictMode -version 2

param (
  [parameter(Mandatory=$false)] [Int32] $windowHeight,
  [parameter(Mandatory=$false)] [Int32] $windowWidth
)

echo "windowHeight: $windowHeight"
echo "windowWidth:  $windowWidth"
```

This error message goes away if I remove the `set-strictMode` statement.

Is it somehow possible to use `set-strictMode -version 2` together with the `param` statement, without getting an error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on [Gert Jan Kraaijeveld's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60696400/45375):

**A `param(...)` block *must* be the *first* statement** in a script (or function) in order to work - with the following **limited exceptions**:

- in v5+, `using` statements may precede it - see [`about_using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_using).
- *comments* may precede it,

  - which includes `#Requires` comments, which state requirements evaluated / ensured before the script runs - see [`about_Requires`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Requires)

---

**Arguably, placing any other statements before `param(...)` should be caught *at parse time***, but as of PowerShell 7.0, the error occurs *at runtime*, which can result in unhelpful error messages:

Technically, what happens is that a command mistakenly placed *before* the `param(...)` block changes the latter's interpretation to considering `param` the name of a *command* (alias, function, script, or executable) - which typically doesn't exist.

Because the misplaced command happened to be a `Set-StrictMode` call in your case, the *arguments* to the command-that-isn't were evaluated first, and a reference to a non-existent `$windowHeight` (which then wasn't treated as a *parameter* variable) caused the strict-mode error you saw.

Had you placed a different command first, the misinterpretation of `param` as a *command name* would have become more obvious:

> `The term 'param' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. [...]`

While this is better than the misleading strict-mode error, as stated, a *parse-time error* with a *dedicated, specific* error message would be much better.

Answer (score 1):

The param statement should come first. So move the Set-StrictMode line a few lines down. Then it works. Make the parameters mandatory if you want them provided at all times